# problem on conditioning in total variance law

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, variance

I faced a problem while conditioning to compute the variance, the problem states that there are two random variables $X,Y$ described by joined PDF which is constant within the area within vertices $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,2)$ and I supposed to find $var(X+Y)$ using total variance law, So I started defining $Z = X+Y$, as $var(Z) = E[var(Z|Y)] + var(E[Z|Y])$,
`Note : I know that conditioning on X will make the problem easier but I went through conditioning on Y`

$$E[Z|Y=y] = E[X+Y|Y=y]=E[X+y|Y=y]= E[X|Y=y]+y$$
so trying to compute $E[X|Y=y]$ I said that $E[X|Y=y] = E[X|Y=y,Y>=1]P(Y>=1) + E[X|Y=y,Y<1]P(Y<1)= \quad \mathbf{2y}$

as $f_{X|Y,Y>=1}(x|y)$ is uniformly distributed such that $x \in [y-1,1]$ as $x$ is bounded by $x=1$ and $x=y-1$ so $f_{X|Y,Y>=1}(x|y)={1 \over 2-y}$,
 Also $f_{X|Y,Y<1}(x|y)$ is uniformly distributed such that $x \in [0,y]$, bounded by $x=0$ and $x=y$ so $f_{X|Y,Y<1}(x|y)={1 \over y}$, and $P(Y<1)=P(Y>=1) = {1 \over 2}$

$var(Z|Y=y)=var(X+Y|Y=y)=var(X+y|Y=y) = var(X|Y=y)$

So how could I compute $var(X|Y=y)$ as there are $f_{X|Y,Y>=1}(x|y),\space and\space f_{X|Y,Y<1}(x|y)$?

Comment: Wow, how to make things complicated... What happens if one simply tries to compute the PDF of $Z=X+Y$? Drawing the domain of the PDF of $(X,Y)$, one gets readily $$f_Z(z)=\tfrac12z\mathbf 1_{(0,1)}(z)+\tfrac12\mathbf 1_{(1,2)}(z)+\tfrac12(3-z)\mathbf 1_{(2,3)}(z)$$ and the moments of $Z$ follow, for example $$E(Z)=\tfrac32$$ is direct (by symmetry or otherwise).

Comment: actually I just wanted to ensure my understanding of total variance that is why I worked through all of this, also the problem stated that I should solve it using Total variance law. I will add it now.

Comment: Or, drawing the domain did recommended, notice that $(X,Y)$ is distributed as $(X,X+U)$, where $(X,U)$ are uniform over the unit square.  Hence $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y) = \operatorname{Var}(2X+U) = 4/12+1/12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed easier ways to do this, but if you *must* go down this route, express the functions using indicators or such, to better keep track of the pieces.

Since $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y) = \frac 1y\mathbf 1_{y\in[0;1), x\in[0;y]}+\frac 1{2-y}\mathbf 1_{y\in [1;2], x\in[y-1;1]}$, by virtue of being uniformly distributed along segment of the horizontal line at $y$ passing through the rhombus, therefore: $$\displaystyle\mathsf E(X\mid Y=y) ~{= \mathbf 1_{y\in[0;1)}\int_0^y \frac xy\operatorname d x + \mathbf 1_{y\in [1;2]}\int_{y-1}^1 \frac x{2-y}\operatorname d x \\ = \frac y2\mathbf 1_{y\in [0;1)}+\frac y2\mathbf 1_{y\in[1;2]}\\= \frac 12y\,\mathbf 1_{y\in[0;2]}}$$

And similarly, 
$$\displaystyle\mathsf {Var}(X\mid Y=y) ~{= \mathbf 1_{y\in[0;1)}\int_0^y \frac {(x-y/2)^2}y\operatorname d x + \mathbf 1_{y\in [1;2]}\int_{y-1}^1 \frac {(x-y/2)^2}{2-y}\operatorname d x \\ = \frac {y^2}{12}\mathbf 1_{y\in [0;1)}+\frac {y(13y^2-24y+12)}{2-y}\mathbf 1_{y\in[1;2]}}$$

---

Now, using $f_Y(y)= y\mathbf 1_{y\in[0;1)}+(2-y)\mathbf 1_{y\in[1;2]}~$ find $\mathsf {Var}(\mathsf {E}(X+Y\mid Y))$ and $\mathsf E(\mathsf {Var}(X+Y\mid Y))$